# Magento Redis - interpreting key value results

Tags: magento-1.9, redis

I have installed redis and see that it is working properly. I understand that it is nosql db and the basic theory around nosql databases.

What I dont understand is that with respect to magento 
1. What exactly is Redis caching ? Is it caching the regularly used items like images, text etc ? 
2. In the image shown below, what exactly are the keys and tags and how do I interpret the results below.

[image]

3. After expanding the keys, I see output as below. How is the below to be interpreted.

[image]

This maybe a simple question for redis users, but am quite new to this and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Redis is a storage engine, it's simply caching Magento system data built by the Magento cache engine in your case system data, query data, CMS data etc. etc. You will see exactly the same data stored in var/cache when Magento uses the file system to cache data. Unless you are caching your own custom data, trying to decipher what is represented by the key id's in Redis is pretty pointless. As long as redis is working and you can see Magento data getting cached I would be happy. Images are not cached by the server.

Comment: @paj Thanks. If i create a full page cache using Lesti or use an opcode php cache, do those also store inside the Redis cache ? For example, when i create the redis cache, i expect to see my var/cache blank, but my lesti fpc is creating a folder insside the var/cache and is probably caching there. Is that the correct way of working ?

Comment: If you configure Lesti FPC to use Redis then it will use Redis. More info on using redis as a Magento cache storage system here http://blog.gaiterjones.com/magento-redis-system-session-and-full-page-cache-management-solution/

Comment: @paj I have seen many resources on this subject, but this is new to me and seems promising. Will go through and revert if any queries. Thanks.